# How to capture the portlet instance removing event from a page in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

When an instance of my portlet is going to be removed from a page, I want to capture that event to get some preference values from that portlet, and to do something.

Is there anything like interfaces or hooks to do that in Liferay?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define your own `PortletLayoutListener` in **liferay-portlet.xml**:

```
<portlet>
        <portlet-name>xxyyzz</portlet-name>
...
        <portlet-layout-listener-class>com.myCompany.MyLayoutTypePortletListener</portlet-layout-listener-class>
...
</portlet>
```

And your **MyLayoutTypePortletListener** may be similar to:

```
public class MyLayoutTypePortletListener
    implements PortletLayoutListener {

    public void onRemoveFromLayout(String portletId, long plid)
        throws PortletLayoutListenerException {
        // ***** ... your LOGIC HERE *****
    }

    public void onMoveInLayout(String portletId, long plid)
        throws PortletLayoutListenerException {

    }

    public void onAddToLayout(String portletId, long plid)
        throws PortletLayoutListenerException {
    }

}
```

---

See the journal content portlet for an example and that [Liferay's Forum Post](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11290898).